# how to configure acl http_status 403 in Squid-Cache?

Tags: proxy, squid, http-status-codes

I have this rule to redirect TCP_DENIED/403, TCP_DENIED_REPLY/403, TCP_MISS/403 to `deny.log`

```
acl DENY_ACCESS http_status 403
access_log stdio:/var/log/squid/deny.log squid DENY_ACCESS
```

But I get messages like this in `cache.log`

```
2023/11/21 16:30:43 kid1| WARNING: DENY_ACCESS ACL is used in context without an HTTP response. Assuming mismatch.
    connection: conn41749 local=192.168.0.10:3128 remote=192.168.0.146:50389 FD 1742 flags=1
```

How can I avoid or hide them? Thk